# Creating Schema automatically using migration in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to create schemas automatically in the database when xampp is turning on? There is no information about it in the Laravel documentation, documentation says only how to do it manually by writing the command **php artisan migrate**.

Comment: There's no way out of the box to automatically run migrations based on your webserver status change. Continuous integration (Jenkis, TravisCI, etc.) can do this by setting jobs (`git pull ...`, followed by `php artisan migrate`, etc.), but that is quite a broad concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xampp includes a script called apache_startup.bat in the root directory, you can add the following line to it

`c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f /path/to/laravel/app/artisan migrate`

Then when the apache server starts, it should run that the equivalent of php artisan migrate to setup the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do **php artisan make:migration [migration-name]** - other than that, you have to fill the rest yourself.